# Laravel image validation on update

Tags: laravel

My form field looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-6 fv-row form-group" id="file_upload">
    <label class="fs-6 fw-bold mb-2" for="file">
        File Upload
    </label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" onchange="loadPreview(this);" class="form-control form-control-solid @error('file_upload') is-invalid @enderror"
        id="file_upload"  value="" />
    <div class="kt_preview_image_container">
        <img id="kt_preview_img" src="{{asset('uploads/settings/'.$setting->file_name)}}" class="img-fluid"/>
        <a href="!#" class="kt_preview_image_close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
    </div>
    @error('file_upload')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

And my validation looks like this:

```
'file_upload' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048'
```

But in case of update, let's say I don't want to change this image field, instead, I just want to change the title filed, but in this case, it is throwing error that, file_upload is required, how could I fix should, should I be uploading image on every update or what? How, could I populate old image value here?

Comment: make it nullable `'file_upload' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048'`

Comment: What if user intentionally don't upload it? because it is the required field by the way.

Comment: How do you differentiate between create or update?

Comment: @apokryfos could differentiate using Post / Put method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requiredIf`

```
'file_upload' =>[Rule::requiredIf(function (){

      if (!empty(ModelName::find($this->id)->file_upload)) {

         return false;
      }

        return true;

     }),'image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg','max:2048']
```

Also you can change if condition to

```
if (ModelName::whereNotNull('file_upload')->where('id',$this->id)->exists()) {
    
           return false;
    }
    
          return true;
    })
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: I got the idea, as it seems more logical to implement you solution. But, on edit, I am showing a preview image of currently set image.

So, in case of update, let's say user clear that (removed that image), and didn't upload another image, in that case shouldn't I throw the message, that now file Upload is passed?

Comment: @AayushDahal when user click remove image then call ajax to delete file and update database table row. so when user submit form again validation will throw required error

Comment: any other idea? Because, I am not submitting this form via ajax, so, user might not notice that the image will be delete permanently just hitting that clear button, without hitting the submit button.

Comment: @AayushDahal submit form as normal.but add button to delete image if already exist then while clicking delete image button call ajax call

Answer (score 0):

on your update method, you can change the validation and check for condition if the file exists on the request

```
'file_upload' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048'

if($request->hasFile('file_upload')) {
    // if you want to delete previous image
    if(file_exists('path/'.$setting->file_name) {
        unlink('path/'.$setting->file_name);
    }
    $file = $request->file('file_upload');
    $extension = $file->extension();
    $fileName = 'your-file-name';
    $upload = $file->storeAs('path', $fileName);
    $setting->file_name = $fileName;
}
```